# How to Revalidate when data in fetcher is change using swr

Tags: javascript, next.js, fetch, swr

I want to revalidate the date when on change. This is what I tried:

```
const fetchData = async() => {
  const {
    data
  } = await axios.get(`/api/admin/orders${criteria}`, {
    params: {
      name: debouncedValue,
    },
  });
  return data;
};
const {
  data,
  error: err,
  mutate,
} = useSWR(`/api/admin/orders${criteria}/${nameSearch}`, fetchData);
const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent < HTMLInputElement > ) => {
  mutate();
  setNameSearch(e.target.value);
};
```

But the data is no revalidate, I have to use the `onTabFocus` revalidation.